# How to get the ID of a guild on join in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need the bot to get the guild ID on join for an api. At the moment I've tried this, but I get an error:

`Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

My code

```
client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => {
  request(
    {
      url:
        "https://urlgoeshere" +
        client.guild.id +
        "/" +
        key +
        "/" +
        client.guild.memberCount,
    },
    function (error, httpResponse, body) {
      console.error("error:", error); 
      console.log("body:", body); 
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you try to get `guild.id` and `guild.memberCount` from `client`.

[guildCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) callback parameter returns the [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) joined, so modify as following :

```js
client.on("guildCreate", (guild) => {
  request(
    {
      url:
        "https://urlgoeshere" +
        guild.id +
        "/" +
        key +
        "/" +
        guild.memberCount,
    },
    function (error, httpResponse, body) {
      console.error("error:", error); 
      console.log("body:", body); 
    }
  );
});
```